# What is the Complexity (BigO) of this Algorithm?

Tags: big-o, time-complexity

[image]

I'm fairly new to the Big-O stuff and I'm wondering what's the complexity of the algorithm.

I understand that every addition, if statement and variable initialization is O(1).

From my understanding first 'i' loop will run 'n' times and the second 'j' loop will run 'n^2' times. Now, the third 'k' loop is where I'm having issues.

Is it running '(n^3)/2' times since the average value of 'j' will be half of 'n'?

Does it mean the Big-O is O((n^3)/2)?

Comment: "Drop the constants" is the Big-O mantra. And yes, you are right the algorithm is O(N^3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use Sigma notation to calculate the number of iterations of the inner-most *basic operation*  of you algorithm, where we consider the `sum = sum + A[k]` to be a basic operation.

[image: Sigma not.]

Now, how do we infer that `T(n)` is in `O(n^3)` in the last step, you ask?

Let's loosely define what we mean by Big-O notation:

> `f(n) = O(g(n))` means `c · g(n)` is an **upper bound** on `f(n)`. Thus 
>   there exists some constant `c` such that `f(n)` is always `≤ c · g(n)`, 
>   **for sufficiently large `n`** (i.e. , `n ≥ n0` for some constant `n0`).

I.e., we want to find *some* (non-unique) set of positive constants `c` and `n0` such that the following holds

```
 |f(n)| ≤ c · |g(n)|, for some constant c>0                   (+)
                      for n sufficiently large (say, n>n0)
```

for some function `g(n)`, which will show that `f(n)` is in `O(g(n))`.

Now, in our case, `f(n) = T(n) = (n^3 - n^2) / 2`, and we have:

```
f(n) = 0.5·n^3 - 0.5·n^2

{ n > 0 } => f(n) = 0.5·n^3 - 0.5·n^2 ≤ 0.5·n^3 ≤ n^3

    => f(n) ≤ 1·n^3                                           (++)
```

Now `(++)` is exactly `(+)` with `c=1` (and choose `n0` as, say, `1`, `n>n0=1`), and hence, we have shown that `f(n) = T(n)` is in `O(n^3)`.

---

From the somewhat formal derivation above it's apparent that any constants in function `g(n)` can just be extracted and included in the constant `c` in `(+)`, hence you'll never (at least should not) see time complexity described as e.g. `O((n^3)/2)`. When using Big-O notation, we're describing an upper bound on the *asymptotic behaviour* of the algorithm, hence only the dominant term is of interest (however not how this is scaled with constants).